# (NSMergeConflict for NSManagedObject) error due to duplicate instances of MOC or data model

Tags: cocoa, ios4, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Does anybody know if a (NSMergeConflict for NSManagedObject) error while trying to remove/erase a record is primarily due to multiple instances of MOC or could it be related to an modified data model issue?

any ideas on who to debug it? Is there any facility in xcode that show me all the active instance of objects and its classes while debugging?

Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206335/ios-core-data-error-nsmergeconflict-for-nsmanagedobject) at SO, does this apply to your situation? Else you should provide some  information on your setup.

Comment: I had seen this conversation before. The issue I am having is that the core data model works fine, saves and deletes as needed through some processes but does not through other. I have a system that manages personal reminders. When a reminder expires it ask you if you want to delete it or not. And it works fine.

Comment: continued .....But if I go through the UIView that shows the list of all reminders and try to delete from there it does not delete it, but throw the (NSMergeConflict for NSManagedObject) exception. The weird thing is that both ways to delete use the same functionality/methods. So I think there is a duplicate MOC running out there. I was wondering if there is any tool to determine at any time what objects are alive in memory.